# Windows network interface monitoring

Tags: powershell, nagios

I am trying to get the interface performance metrics through nagios and nsclient++ by executing a PowerShell script. Main part of the powershell script is below.

```
Function netstat {
  '{0:0}' -f (Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface |
    where{$_.Name -eq "vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter"} |
    select BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec) / 1KB)
}
```

I want the output to be in MB/s and change the header to `Tx MB/s` and `Rx MB/s`. Right now I am getting the following output.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | where{$_.Name -eq "vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter"} | select BytesReceivedPersec, BytesSentPersec

                 BytesReceivedPersec                   BytesSentPersec
                 -------------------                   ---------------
                         12720975895                         438054511
```

I also tried using the `check_wmi` module of nsclient++ like this.

```
check_nrpe -H 10.35.136.221 -c check_wmi -a 'query=select BytesReceivedPersec, BytesSentPersec from Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface where name = "vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter"'
```

And I get the following output.

```
12719626616, 437766199
```

How can I make the output of the above check result like below?

```
Rx MB/s : 12719626616 Tx MB/s : 437766199
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for changing property names and/or values. Change this:

```
... | select BytesReceivedPersec, BytesSentPersec
```

into this:

```
... | select @{n='Rx MB/s';e={$_.BytesReceivedPersec / 1MB}},
             @{n='Tx MB/s';e={$_.BytesSentPersec / 1MB}}
```

---

**Edit:** If all you want is a formatted output string you don't need to bother with calculated properties. Just build the formatted string:

```
... | % {
  'OK | Rx MB/s={0:0}; Tx MB/s={1:0}' -f ($_.BytesReceivedPersec / 1MB),
    ($_.BytesSentPersec / 1MB)
}
```

Comment: That works and Thank you, Ansgar. However, I am concerned if this is the right way to get network statistics of an interface. I tried copying a file over the machine in question and was monitoring task manager and the output of this command. They don't seem to reflect the same thing or Am I wrong?

Comment: @RajS You may want to query the [`Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class instead.

Comment: Function netstat {

$nstat = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | where{$_.Name -eq "vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter"} | select @{n="Rx MB/s";e={$_.BytesReceivedPersec 

/ 1MB}}, @{n="Tx MB/s";e={$_.BytesSentPersec / 1MB}}
'OK | {0:0}' -f ($nstat)

}. I am trying to get the output of this function as 'OK | Tx MB/s = ..., Rx MB/s = ..., but I am getting the following output. OK |'@{Rx'=0 'MB/s'=0 'Tx'=0 'MB/s'=0}

Comment: Hi Ansgar, By this method my nagios server is only polling the Windows host every 10 minutes. Is it possible to get the statistics data for the past 10 mins so when nagios polls every 10 minutes, it gets the data for the whole interval?

Comment: @RajS That's a question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), but yes, there are ways.